# PowerShell script runs in ISE but not as a script

Tags: powershell

OBJECTIVES :-

I'm having trouble with something that should be relatively simple? Searched similar questions here but no cigar. I dont want to have to pass a command to the file as a Ps1 script (common suggestion). I'm hoping I can just right click, run with PowerShell and it works.

SITUATION :-

I have to automate uninstalling of software often. Rather than scour the registry for msiexec strings, I edited some PS code so I can search for what I want, then do whatever I need to do with the info I receive. The below runs fine in PowerShell ISE, but as a PS1 script (right click, run with PS) it outputs nothing on the screen.

CODE :-

```
$Prog = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your Prog name'
Get-ChildItem -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall, HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall | Get-ItemProperty | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -match "$Prog"} | Select-Object -Property DisplayName, UninstallString

pause
```

Lets say at the prompt I search for 7-Zip in ISE I get this...

```
Input your Prog name: 7-zip

DisplayName       UninstallString                     
-----------       ---------------                     
7-Zip 19.00 (x64) C:\Program Files\7-Zip\Uninstall.exe
```

Running as a script, I get nothing output into the console?

```
Input your Prog name: 7-zip

Press Enter to continue...:
```

QUESTION :- What do I need to do to make the script behave like it does in the ISE console?

Many thanks for any assistance

P.S (<see what I did there, I'm new to the PowerShell game, thanks>)

Answer (score 1):

It works in Powershell too, if you run it from Powershell Interactive Prompt or run using `powershell -file "FILEPATH"` in CMD/PowerShell, the output remains on the screen. But when you run directly with a double-click output doesn't stay persistent on the screen, instead when it reaches EOF then it quits. So, Add `Read-Host` or `cmd /c pause` at the end to stop the program at the end, to view output.

Comment: There must be a way I can right click the file, run with powershell and get the results, i know I can CMD to it, but seems so clunky?

Comment: No currently there are nothing so but you can add it